# Failed to load linked library swiftQuartzCore of module RxSwift - errors:

Tags: xcode, rx-swift

My project git repo was at https://github.com/jiexishede/RxSwiftTimePlayground.
When I ran the playground page, the error will show :

```
error: error while processing module import: Failed to load linked library swiftQuartzCore of module RxSwift - errors:
```

I don't know why.

```
Xcode: 15.1 RxSwift 6.1.0 RxCocoa 6.1.0
```

I have searched on github: https://github.com/kodecocodes/rxs-materials/issues/1.

Comment: I know it's something to do with the playground code itself. I have a project that has several playgrounds that work and when I dragged yours in, I get the error.

Answer (score 1):

I got your repo to work by moving all the code into the playground page and removing the access restrictions. Also, I added a view controller so I could see the output. I sent you a PR.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Cocoapod to install RxSwift.
Now I install the RxSwift by SPM（Swift Package Manager）. The demo works.